# Term for introducing a new work/idea that is different in some aspects relative to previous ones

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, technical, technology

How to introduce a work, e.g. a publication or report, in a field in which there are many similar works but the new one considered the topic from another perspective that is not common among previous works by using a phrase or single word.

> e.g. Our work, as a _____ , tries to look at the topic from a new perspective to take into account other influential factors.

Comment: You already use the phrase "new perspective"; why do you need another phrase that means the same thing?

Comment: I’d keep your relatives out of it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use ***innovative approach/strategy***. *Innovative* means

> featuring new methods; advanced and original.
>
> - *innovative* designs ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=innovative%20meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB976GB976&biw=1536&bih=722&sxsrf=ALiCzsbtatfa9_ei45pCwwkiQZciGY7JSw%3A1660673304692&ei=GN37YsjpKciR8gKyl5eQAg&ved=0ahUKEwjI1aeT-sv5AhXIiFwKHbLLBSI4ChDh1QMIDg&uact=5&oq=innovative%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgjECcyCAgAEB4QDxAHMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBAgAEB4yBQgAEIYDMgUIABCGAzoICAAQHhAPEAhKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQAFgAYIEJaABwAHgAgAGAAYgB9QGSAQMwLjKYAQDAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz))

Answer (score 2):

a groundbreaking study or article or research

Oxford Dictionary via Google

ground·break·ing
/ˈɡroundˌbrākiNG/

adjective
breaking new ground; innovative; pioneering.
"**groundbreaking** research into fertility problems"

Answer (score 0):

> Our _______ report, tries to look at the topic from a new perspective to take into account other influential factors.

***reworked**, tweaked, anew, afresh

renewed, revised, reshaped*

Take your pick or synonym search in thesauri. I myself would go with *reworked*.

Answer (score 0):

> Our work is a **game changer** because it looks at the topic from a
> new perspective and takes into account other influential factors.

Game changer:

[An idea or event that significantly changes the way something is done or thought about](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/game+changer)